# Azure Push Notifications : Receiving push messages after switching On/Off Wifi or Mobile Data

Tags: azure, xamarin, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android

I am working on Xamarin.Android and using Azure mobile services to do push messages. Whenever I send push messages through Notifications hubs, they do not reach my Android phone but if I switch **Off/On** my WiFi connection or Mobile Data only then it comes to mobile. What could be the problem ?

Comment: I have similar setup but no issues at all, just tested it ..

Comment: There could be issues based on mobile hand set ? 
Did you specify some additional code regarding wake_time etc ?

Comment: no, I did not, but I used azure push notification component (sample code was a bit outdated)

Comment: Yeah, I am also using the component but notifications comes only after switching internet on-off

Comment: Are you registering for gcm in your Application class?

Comment: By Application class ? you meant MainActivity class ? If yes then yeah I am registering for GCM there only and Receiving messages in different class which inherits from GcmServiceBase

Comment: no, I'm registering mine in the Application class `OnCreate()` method

Comment: Mine is also in OnCreate() method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100465/discussion-between-superb-and-milen-pavlov).